# VB- save offline txt file to server when connected to network

Tags: vb6, excel, vba

I have written a Excel VB  to save a file to sharepoint from an automated task. It works fine if it is connected to office network. If I am offline , I save the file to local drive .  Can somebody help me with a macro to save the file to server  when computer is connected to office network?  My office does not recommend checking the network status continuously. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: If the office doesn't recommend checking for the network connectivity then we have only one option. write a macro and manually save the files to the server when you are connected.

Comment: I did not mean that office does not recommend checking for the network. The office does not allow me to run macro that keeps checking for network connectivity as it affects the computer performance.

Comment: @SiddharthRout He could use WMI to check for connectivity, then if no connection exists, schedule another task to check again in N minutes.

Comment: @JP. You are right. I already thought of that. It is the same thing as checking for connections via VBA code in N minutes. And hence I suggested a manual way to run the macro only when the user is connected to the network. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout That would be the easiest solution, to simply wait until connected.

Comment: Why not try to save the file to a network path with error handling. If the error is triggered (ie no connection) then save the file locally and let the user know.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I can check for the connectivity at certain intervals - may be once in a day. But once I upload the file to the server, the checking for connectivity will continue no matter whether I have something to upload or not. Is there a way to tell the computer that there is a pending task to complete so that I need to check only if there is a pending task otherwise no need to check for connectivity- Appreciate your help

Comment: Purpose of Excel automation is to update status of a task by a user ( 500 users around the world) and save it in a sharepoint for the mangement review. When the user is online and update Excel workbook , the status is automatically uploaded to sharepoint. Many a times the users update it offline. Current excel macro checks for connectivity and if there is no connection it saves the file on the local computer. The help I am looking for is, when the user connects the computer online ( first time) i want to upload the local file to sharepoint and delete the local file. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

By automated task do you mean a Scheduled Task?

If so and you happen to be running on Windows 7, you can set Scheduled Tasks to only run if certain network conditions are met. You could build a separate macro that takes any files stored locally and pushes them up to the server and have that macro run only when the network is connected.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Automated task means that i wrote a VB program to collect some data to upload into the server. I should be able to collect data offline from the local computer and upload when it is connected to network. Appreciate your help